# Problem with IAP

Tags: c, flash, ram, lpc

I'm using LPC1788 IAP to write to Flash and I'm a little confused on what's going on. I'm trying to write 8 bytes of data to Flash memory with 2 tehniques:

1) With one which is logical to me and it doesn't work

```
for(i=0; i<8; i++) {
    iap_copy_to_flash(&serial_no[i], OFFSET_SERIAL+i, 1);
    }
```

2) With one which is not logical to me and it works

```
 iap_copy_to_flash((BYTE*)serial_no, OFFSET_SERIAL, 8);
```

> OFFSET SERIAL is 0x00040000 and serial_no[8] is array of BYTES

Why first won't work and second works?

I'm only getting problem when writing array to Flash sector, when writing BYTE, WORD, DWORD variables everything is okay.

Here is iap_copy_to_flash function http://pastebin.com/gNBkVWef and copy_ram_to_flash function http://pastebin.com/uVptXD2D. I will be very thankful if someone explains to me what is wrong with my thinking. Thanks.

Comment: You have forgotten to include the definition of `serial_no`, so we don't know what exactly your piece of code is doing...

Comment: Its array of 8 BYTES.

Comment: Then try `serial_no + i` instead of `&serial_no[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the documentation for those IAP functions. LPC17xx does not allow byte writes to flash, and I am not sure whether DWORD writes are alowed either.

The flash memory itself is wider than one byte (actually 64 bits IIRC) - so you cannot write a single byte without touching others.